# how to use Set-AzDataLakeStoreItemAclEntry to set ACL permission for Service Principal?

Tags: az

how to use Set-AzDataLakeStoreItemAclEntry to set ACL permission for Service Principal?

It allows me to use User as AceType with SP's ObjectID. But icon being used the ACL list will look different. It will be like

If I use:
Set-AzDataLakeStoreItemAclEntry -Account *** -Path /*** -AceType Other -Id "**********"  -Permissions rwx

It will return error message "Error in modifying ACL entries other:ObjectID:rwx for path/*** MODIFYACLENTRIES failed with HttpStatus:Forbidden...."

Answer (score 0):

Issue is on using the right SPN Object ID.

We shall use the Object ID from:
Azure Portal->AAD (azure active directory)->Enterprise Applications (not from app registration)->your app id -> Get the guid from the objectid column